# How to show the input text view in Android

Tags: android, textview

On this screenshot:

[image]

I am looking for the solution to make the UI more decent. I like the blue line for the input box but it only show either User Name or Password only. What is the simplest way to let the 2 blue line appear below User Name and Password in order?

Cheers

Here's what i have tried so  far

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/myBackground"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/voicemeno" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/userName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
            android:text="User Name"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/myText" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/userNameInput"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/userName"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:textColor="@color/myText"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@null" >
        </EditText>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/userNameInput"
            android:text="Password"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/myText" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/passwordInput"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/password"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:textColor="@color/myText"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@null" >
        </EditText>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: explain the problem !

Comment: what do you want exactly ?

Comment: Your code seems fine. Try switching to a `LinearLayout` and see what happens.

Comment: THe problem is I want the blue line can show it in the same time, now it only show the blue line when I mouse clicked it.

Comment: change your background color of `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: @AnthonyLord You have convert the image as a 9 patch image and set is as background to the edittext

Comment: Change either your textviews background or your RelativeLayout background!

Comment: I would like the black color background and want to create the simple and decent UI. SO I only want to find the simplest way can let the blue line input boxes appear on the same page. Hopes for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/myBackground"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" 
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true">

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/voicemeno" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/userName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
                android:text="User Name"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/myText" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/userNameInput"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/userName"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:textColor="@color/myText"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@null" >
            </EditText>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/userNameInput"
                android:text="Password"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/myText" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/passwordInput"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/password"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:textColor="@color/myText"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@null" >
            </EditText>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @AnthonyLord you can make a style that change the bottom border of the edit text to blue

Comment: @AnthonyLord http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/changing-background-color-and-border-color-of-an-edittext-widget-using-state-list-in-android/

Comment: You can use this lib to generate your new selectors
http://android-holo-colors.com/

Comment: @Mahdi Hijazi, I have uploaded the files to my project. But I have no idea how to implement it to my project. Can you explain it more ?

Comment: just use the style from the styles xml file like this style="@style/your_new_style"

Comment: ＠Mahdi Hijazi, does it put the below code to styles.xml

<resources>
@style/your_new_style
</resources>

Comment: @MH; I think I got it. Should be like this 
<TextView
    style="@style/CodeFont"
    android:text="@string/hello" />

Answer (score 0):

you can use a TextView followed by a EditText view for each of the filds(username,password) you want.